# Column not found: 1054 laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Meu código retorna esse erro:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'postagens.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `postagens` where `postagens`.`id` = 1 limit 1)
```

segue meu codigo aqui o controller:

```
public function getEditar($id_postagem){

    $postagem = PostagemDados::find($id_postagem);

    return View::make('postagem.new-edit', compact('postagem'));
}

public function postEditar($id_postagem){
    $postagem = PostagemDados::find($id_postagem);
    $postagem->titulo = Input::get('titulo');
    $postagem->conteudo = Input::get('conteudo');
    $postagem->save();

    return Redirect::to('postagem');
}
```

e aqui a minha view

```
@extends('templates.template')

@section('conteudo')

   <p>Gestão de Postagem</p>

   @if(isset($postagem->id_postagem) )
      {{Form::open(array('url' => "postagem/editar/$postagem->id_postagem", 'class' => 'teste'))}}
   @else
      {{Form::open(array('url' => 'postagem/cadastrar', 'class' => 'teste'))}}
   @endif

  {{Form::text('titulo', isset($postagem->titulo) ? $postagem->titulo :  '', array('placeholder' => 'titulo'))}}
  {{Form::textarea('conteudo', isset($postagem->conteudo) ? $postagem->conteudo : '', array('placeholder' => 'conteudo'))}}
  {{Form::submit('Cadastrar')}}
  {{Form::close()}}

@stop
```

e aqui aminha model:

```
<?php
    class PostagemDados extends Eloquent{
       protected $table = 'postagens';

       protected $primarykey = 'id_postagem';
  }
```

o que pode ser? obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O campo `id` parece não existir no model/tabela, o que está definido nele é `id_postagem`

O erro diz:

> Unknown column 'postagens.id' in 'where clause'

```
where `postagens`.`id`
```

Model:

```
protected $primarykey = 'id_postagem';
```

Comment: mas existe essa tabela no banco de dados, inclusive consigo cadastrar um post

Comment: @EversonSouzadeAraujo mas não existe o campo `id` e sim o `id_postagem`.

Comment: consegui eu mudei o nome da minha coluna no BD e depois mudei os atributos na minha classe. o estranho é que não tinha esse campo id.